# Mod_rewrite Redirecting

Tags: mod-rewrite

I think I finally got the basics of mod_rewrite figured out, but I am still having some trouble.

I want my hypothetical site to direct (almost) all traffic to home.html, which will parse the SEO URLs. This means that /home, /home.html, /index.html, /something/somethingelse/gobledegook all go to home.html (don't worry about passing GET variables, the home file will parse the entire URL later).

Here is the current setup:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/something/I/want/to/preserve.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home.html [L]
```

This works brilliantly. Except it works as a redirect: the URL in browser becomes "/home.html". How do I load the home.html page but keep the URL the same?

Comment: Thanks @Carsten for catching the code formatting.  I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.staging.example.com
RewriteRule ^$ /abc-sp.html [PT,L]
```

Note that the "blank URL-path" test is now done in the rule, so the original RewriteCond is not needed.

The [PT] tells mod_rewrite to leave the output in "URL-format" instead of converting it to a filepath. Thus the rewritten URL-request can then be picked up by mod_proxy and sent to your back-end.

It that doesn't work, then use the [P] flag instead of [PT], and specify the *URL* of your back-end resource, e.g. "http:/ /192.168.0.2:8080/abc-sp.jsp". The [P] flag will generate a reverse-proxy through-put, just as your likely-existing config-file mod_alias code does.

Note that the code above is for .htaccess or for use in a config file *within a  container*. If used outside any  container or .htaccess, add a leading slash to the RewriteRule pattern.

Hope my answer helps! :~)

Answer (score 2):

Simple, use the [passthrough (PT) flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home.html [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply add the `P` flag to your `RewriteRule`. See: [Apache mod_rewrite Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p)

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home.html [PL]
```

Comment: Actually, I think @Cartsen's answer is more correct, although I'm pretty sure mine will work it comes w/ the overhead of mod_proxy.